# Drag drop html table in powerpoint 2007

Tags: interop, drag-and-drop, powerpoint, office-2007

I've been dealing with this problem for quite a while:
Our company develops addins for word/excel/ppt (both for 2003 and 2007 versions)

One of the options our addins offer is to drag a table from the addin into the application.

This is implemented in 3 different ways:

1. Excel --> we create a tab delimeted string and drag-dropping it as DataFormats.text
2. Word --> we create an RTF table, and drag-dropping it as DataFormats.rtf
3. PPT --> we create an HTML table, and drag-dropping it as DataFormats.html

Everything is working great in both the 2003 & 2007, except for the powerpoint 2007, which doesn't seem to support any kind of html dropping (unlike powerpoint 2003, which is working great) We've tried everything but we're beginning to despair.

Anyone knows how to allow PowerPoint 2007 to allow dropping html into the presentation?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a few years late, but still a reply is always good.

I was doing that too. You should convert your HTML to JPEG

```
WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage(temporaryFilePath, @"C:\image.bmp");
websiteToImage.Generate();
slide.Shapes.AddPicture(@"C:\image.bmp", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, oldshapeleft, oldshapetop, oldshapewidth, oldshapeheight);
```

Source found:
[Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)

Comment: Pretty clever, but this means the user won't be able to modify the table, also resizing it may make the text to look horrible

Comment: Another possible solution, which I used afterwards, was: You copy the table into Excel, it will convert the html code with Paste Special into Excel, and with C# you do `sheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial();` and then `sheet.UsedRange.Copy(Missing.Value);`, you copy the paste table and go to PowerPoint `ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste();` and it will be pasted. Now it is ugly format, but you can now loop through that pasted table in Powerpoint and create a new REAL table in Powerpoint which looks better. This overcome that if the table goes multiple rows that the image doesn't exist but the table

Comment: `objTable.Cell(incrementer,l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text=pptshape.Table.Cell(k,l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;` You insert the old table into the new.
`objTable.Cell(incrementer,l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = fontsize;` and with that one you can redefine the size of your text and you don't need to resize anymore. Now you can define the amount of your new table in PPT too `objTable = presentation.Slides[slide.SlideIndex].Shapes.AddTable(amountrowsshown, pptshape.Table.Columns.Count, topsize, leftsize, slide.Master.Width-widthsize,slide.Master.Height- heightsize).Table;`