# Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, html

I would like to create a function in C# that takes a specific webpage and coverts it to a JPG image from within ASP.NET.  **I don't want to do this via a third party or thumbnail service as I need the full image.**  I assume I would need to somehow leverage the webbrowser control from within ASP.NET but I just can't see where to get started.  Does anyone have examples?

Comment: This will be extremely difficult.

Comment: Wow! What a great question. My first reaction is to use the WebBrowser control and use the DrawToBitmap method, but the documentation states, "This method is not supported by this control." Oh, well.

Comment: I've found this great link, but the one mystery that it never explains is how to get the darn control to work from ASP.NET.  http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Get-Web-Site-Thumbnail-Image.aspx

Comment: So I guess DrawToBitmap works. I should get points for that! :O)

Comment: What specifically is stopping it from working?

Comment: I have tested the code from the article and it works fine. The DrawToBitmap method definitely works.

Comment: @SLaks - Difficult is a mindset. How can you say something is difficult unless you try?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok, this was rather easy when I combined several different solutions:

These solutions gave me a thread-safe way to use the WebBrowser from ASP.NET:

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Get-Web-Site-Thumbnail-Image.aspx

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b7cce396-e2b3-42d7-9571-cdc4eb38f3c1/build-a-selfcaching-asp.aspx

This solution gave me a way to convert BMP to JPG:

[Bmp to jpg/png in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665/bmp-to-jpg-png-in-c)

I simply adapted the code and put the following into a .cs:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class WebsiteToImage
{
    private Bitmap m_Bitmap;
    private string m_Url;
    private string m_FileName = string.Empty;

    public WebsiteToImage(string url)
    {
        // Without file 
        m_Url = url;
    }

    public WebsiteToImage(string url, string fileName)
    {
        // With file 
        m_Url = url;
        m_FileName = fileName;
    }

    public Bitmap Generate()
    {
        // Thread 
        var m_thread = new Thread(_Generate);
        m_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        m_thread.Start();
        m_thread.Join();
        return m_Bitmap;
    }

    private void _Generate()
    {
        var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
        browser.Navigate(m_Url);
        browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        browser.Dispose();
    }

    private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Capture 
        var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        browser.ClientSize = new Size(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
        browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
        browser.BringToFront();
        browser.DrawToBitmap(m_Bitmap, browser.Bounds);

        // Save as file? 
        if (m_FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            // Save 
            m_Bitmap.SaveJPG100(m_FileName);
        }
    }
}

public static class BitmapExtensions
{
    public static void SaveJPG100(this Bitmap bmp, string filename)
    {
        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        bmp.Save(filename, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
    }

    public static void SaveJPG100(this Bitmap bmp, Stream stream)
    {
        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        bmp.Save(stream, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
    }

    public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (var codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }

        // Return 
        return null;
    }
}
```

And can call it as follows:

```
WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage( "http://www.cnn.com", @"C:\Some Folder\Test.jpg");
websiteToImage.Generate();
```

It works with both a file and a stream.  **Make sure you add a reference to System.Windows.Forms to your ASP.NET project.** I hope this helps.

**UPDATE: I've updated the code to include the ability to capture the full page and not require any special settings to capture only a part of it.**

Comment: @SLaks - Why? What specifically is your concern? Using the WebBrowser control is not so different from charting controls that generate an image for display. I do not necessarily agree that threading should be used. I probably would use Control.Invoke and let the control deal with it.

Comment: @AMissico: I don't think that WinForms controls work reliably in a non-interactive session.  I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @Amissico From the first article: First, being a Windows Form control, this must operate on an STA (Single Threaded Apartment) thread. This means you need to either set the AspCompat = "true" attribute on the page that uses it, or you need to make the actual Webbrowser Navigate call to the target page on a secondary thread whose state has been set to STA. I choose the latter.

Comment: @Nissan Fan - Okay, I understand now. Yet, why did the code work for me unmodified? Even with AspCompat="true|false" it still worked. (I was using VS2k8 with local ASP.NET Development Server.)

Comment: Because in the code, the thread is launced as a STA thread thus it solves the problem.

Comment: This may work better on the server if the thumbnailing processing is done from a windows service, That may provide some more "interactvity"?

Comment: I'm not using it for thumbnails, though it could be.

Comment: Wow, great work done in 9 minuttes (time between the question and the answer).

Comment: Thanks Espo.  I didn't have a lot of time to invest in this and I managed to get a real good start from a search I did after posting.

Comment: is   private string m_FileName = string.Empty; where to put file in wich will my image be saved?

Comment: I'm having difficulty passing in parameters into the webbrowser control. Thinking says it should be possible to  do 
'code'(var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
        browser.Navigate("http://someurl.com?params=x");) 

I've also tried msdn's [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161355.aspx) recommendations for passing postData. Don't get why its in byte[] format and how to retrieve the data from within my conttrol's page. Thanks

Comment: @CatManDo The thing work perfect but i am having issue with speed its currently too slow, maybe takes 40-50 sec to save a page i am running it on group on deals.

Comment: This mostly works for me - except I get a bunch of blank areas in my image, which seem to correspond to sections that are rendered using javascript/after document.ready. Is there a way to get that segment to render as well?

Comment: Very nice. Any way to render the image without writing to a file?

Comment: @o365spo Yes simply call the method with a Stream parameter instead of a filename.

Comment: This does not work on an IIS server. It's very slow and it gives me a blank JPG file. It is also missing some CCS images when running locally.

Comment: Why is the `Application.DoEvents();` required?

Comment: @BornToCode not technically needed, but let's your app free up event cycles for other things.

Comment: The WebBrowser control has a known memory leak discussed on many posts here on SO, so this approach might be a bit problematic if you use it on a server which suppose to capture hundreds of pages, don't you think so?

Comment: will not compile: The type or namespace name 'WebBrowser' could not be found, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs could not be found.

Comment: @SteveStaple Just add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: @KeithAdler  I am trying to convert a page that contains Google Charts and  this does not convert to jpg.  Is it possible that svg is not supported?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Good solution by Mr Cat Man Do.

I've needed to add a row to suppress some errors that came up in some webpages
(with the help of an awesome colleague of mine)

```
private void _Generate()
{
    var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };

    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;        //           <--

    browser.Navigate(m_Url);
    browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
}
```

...

Thanks Mr Do

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation using extension methods and task factory instead thread:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Convert url to bitmap byte array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">Url to browse</param>
    /// <param name="width">width of page (if page contains frame, you need to pass this params)</param>
    /// <param name="height">heigth of page (if page contains frame, you need to pass this params)</param>
    /// <param name="htmlToManipulate">function to manipulate dom</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">in milliseconds, how long can you wait for page response?</param>
    /// <returns>bitmap byte[]</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// byte[] img = new Uri("http://www.uol.com.br").ToImage();
    /// </example>
    public static byte[] ToImage(this Uri url, int? width = null, int? height = null, Action<HtmlDocument> htmlToManipulate = null, int timeout = -1)
    {
        byte[] toReturn = null;

        Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser() { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
            browser.Navigate(url);

            browser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                var browserSender = (WebBrowser)s;

                if (browserSender.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    if (htmlToManipulate != null) htmlToManipulate(browserSender.Document);

                    browserSender.ClientSize = new Size(width ?? browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, height ?? browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
                    browserSender.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                    browserSender.BringToFront();

                    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(browserSender.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browserSender.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom))
                    {
                        browserSender.DrawToBitmap(bmp, browserSender.Bounds);
                        toReturn = (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
                    }
                }

            };

            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            browser.Dispose();

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        tsk.Wait(timeout);

        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using tasks...not wild about the use of ext method though.  Also, why not pass Size, TimeSpan, etc?  Those structs are there for a reason...

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article by Peter Bromberg on this subject [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b7cce396-e2b3-42d7-9571-cdc4eb38f3c1/build-a-selfcaching-asp.aspx). His solution seems to do what you need...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is perfect, just needs a fixation in the line which sets the WIDTH of the image. For pages with a LARGE HEIGHT, it does not set the WIDTH appropriately:

```
    //browser.ClientSize = new Size(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
    browser.ClientSize = new Size(1000, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
```

And for adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms, you should do it in .NET-tab of ADD REFERENCE instead of COM -tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WatiN](http://watin.org/) to open a new browser, then capture the screen and crop it appropriately.

Comment: This will require staring a real browser in it's own process. Not really a solution that scales well.