# Google instant - How is the page snapshot generated?

Tags: search, instant, google-instant

When we click on magnifying glass icon, in google instant search, a snapshot of the web page is shown with results hightlighted. What technologies are used to generate that web-page snapshot and search string highlighting ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net