# Dynamically capture an image of a specific url in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to capture an image of a specific URL in asp.net C#. I can't find any thing on the web.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net).

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4712/generate-an-image-of-a-web-page/) , you will get exact code and description also.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a web service like http://www.websnapr.com/, which has both free and paid models depending on your usage needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you're trying to get that URL Thumbnail image that certain blog posts and google provide ?

There isn't actually a method to do exactly what you're asking for because what you need is a web browser to see how a web-page looks.

What normally happens is that an automatic process opens the URL in a browser and takes a screen shot of the window.

Similarly, you can open a Browser control and capture it's window; but I've always been a bit wary of this approach as if there's anything on that URL that demands attention (like a modal popup), it has the potential to lock your thread.

The approach we took was to have a service that was subscribed to, to capture an image and it then managed its own threading and reported urls that gave us trouble.

Comment: you making the assumption that I have a text box and user import url to get url thumbnail image . I want to do this .

Comment: I am indeed, but your question is lacking in significant detail. Refine your question and I'll refine my answer.