# Grab the screenshot url from web page

Tags: php

I am doing an application in which I want to get the screen shots url of the the google apps.Here I could grab the webpage of a particular apps and in that page screen shot urls are inside the div (... ).This div also contain title,width etc.But I want to get the screenshot url only.How can I get screenshot url.
  My application now displays the following array.

```
Array ( 
[0] => src="https://lh5.ggpht.comV07YvaK8lOPyiXOQmC4xTce7VskJzhavKOkEhoMw4KWnFNfOBB8ruIiVmRKhJ6nq8aE=h230" [1] => class="doc-screenshot-img 
[2] => lightbox 
[3] => goog-inline-block"data-baseUrl="https://lh5.ggpht.com/V07YvaK8lOPyiXOQmC4xTce7VskJzhavKOkEhoMw4KWnFNfOBB8ruIiVmRKhJ6nq8aE" 
[4] => title="Angry 
[5] => Birds 
[6] => Space" 
[7] => itemprop="screenshots" 
[8] => />)
```

Comment: it's for ASP.NET but im sure you'll understand the tricks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're after here.

Try (jQuery)

```
// Cycle through all screenshots
$('.doc-screenshot-img')​.each(function() {
    // Get the URL to the screenshot
    $(this).attr('src');             
});​
```