# To save webpage as image

Tags: c#

I have to save webpage as image by passing page URL,i have found one solution on this thread [[Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)[^] but it doesn't give me proper image(e.g. tried URL http://www.bugmuncher.com/).

Also tried [HTML to Image in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58605/HTML-to-Image-in-C)[^] but not able to deal with IViewObject interface ,basically not able to add reference to get this interface.

I have to do something like http://www.usersnap.com does.I made it work on FF,Chrome and IE9 by using canvas element which is unfortunately not supported by IE8.

Can i get proper working solution for my need???

Comment: When you state the the answer on SO doesn't give you a proper image what do you mean?

Comment: I believe this is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

i think you mean taking a screenshot.
Here you are a link about it.

[Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

But here i found on the site that **just you want**. Please check it.

[Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

The webpage can be saved as image by 2 methods.
1. Press ctrl+p 
2. Select "Send to onenote" in print prompt window.
3. Press ok.
Now the image can be saved from the microsoft office -> microsoft onenotebook and rightclick on your content. save as the image file. 
Second method is by using snapshot via snipping tool.