# How to save a webpage as image from a web application

Tags: c#

Is it possible to save web page as image with web application? if yes then how?.I searched and searched and searched but all examples i found were for windows application and i'm facing lot of trouble while converting that code for web application.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)

Comment: Are you trying to capture the webpage as a image, or fetch images as well as HTML from the webpage?

Comment: I hope this link will helps you  http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4712/generate-an-image-of-a-web-page/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you do it through javascript. There is a option. You could also consider activeX if it is targeted for IE.

Please look at the following link for JS Screenshots,

[Screeshots using javascript](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/03/screenshot-in-javascript/)

Comment: I guess this is OS dependent ,coz when i tried to see their demo (http://learningthreejs.com/data/lets_do_a_sky/lets_do_a_sky.html) it gives me this message 'Your graphics card does not seem to support WebGL.'(My OS version Windows 2003)