# System.Windows.WebBrowser captures image of page as its rendered in quirks mode

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, quirks-mode, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am using following link to capture web page as image [Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net).

On few pages I am getting issue where the image created is not similar to actual page but its same as to page displayed in quirks mode(where the page is messed up).
Is there any way to programmatically change the behavior of control(without making any registry changes)

Comment: Looks like the only way to change `WebBrowser` rendering mode - except of changing registry - is to add *document compatibility* tags into HTML code of your pages. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx) from [official blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/) of Internet Explorer team the only two ways to change compatibility mode of `WebBrowser` control are:

1. Add [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) key to the registry for your application
2. Specify compatibility mode within HTML code of web page using [!DOCTYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#whentouse) and/or [meta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#setmode) tags

**Please note**: Default mode of rendering pages by [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may depend on Internet Explorer version installed on machine, as it uses components of Internet Explorer. For IE8 by default `WebBrowser` renders pages in IE7 standards mode.

Part of your application's pages may fall back to older mode (*quirks mode*) due to crash of more modern render (which in fact can differ from one that is used when page is opened directly in IE) caused by some content on the page.

To resolve described problem you can alter HTML code of corrupt pages with [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) property of `WebBrowser` class in order to explicitly specify [document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is appropriate for the pages (i.e. ensures proper rendering).