# Render the contents of webpage to image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF app. I want to render the contents of a webpage to an image. How can I do this? The functionality should also support the pages which have scrollbars (the content is bigger than the container).

Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with [awesomium easily](http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c-net/) [including whole page size](http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c/). But it isn't free.
CEF(chromium embedded framework) should provide same functionality, as long as it based on the same WebKit.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't there a free alternative to this one?

Comment: Well look at C# wrappers on chromium: [WebKit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/), [CEF sharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp) etc.

Comment: I found the answer in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net Thanks for the answer though.