# How to export/save web page as an image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to take screenshot of page and save it as image.  The page has several div tags and different contents in each div like one div tag has chart and the other might have gridview.  So i am trying to take snapshot of the page ans save it as image.  Can someone please help me here as i have googled and could not find any good resources about this.  thanks.

Comment: http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/  save the trouble and use this

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work.  I got this from [Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)

use:

```
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Drawing.Imaging;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   public class WebsiteToImage
   {
private Bitmap m_Bitmap;
private string m_Url;
private string m_FileName = string.Empty;

public WebsiteToImage(string url)
{
    // Without file 
    m_Url = url;
}

public WebsiteToImage(string url, string fileName)
{
    // With file 
    m_Url = url;
    m_FileName = fileName;
}

public Bitmap Generate()
{
    // Thread 
    var m_thread = new Thread(_Generate);
    m_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    m_thread.Start();
    m_thread.Join();
    return m_Bitmap;
}

private void _Generate()
{
    var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
    browser.Navigate(m_Url);
    browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

    while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    browser.Dispose();
}

private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Capture 
    var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    browser.ClientSize = new Size(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
    browser.BringToFront();
    browser.DrawToBitmap(m_Bitmap, browser.Bounds);

    // Save as file? 
    if (m_FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        // Save 
        m_Bitmap.SaveJPG100(m_FileName);
    }
}
 }

 public static class BitmapExtensions
 {
  public static void SaveJPG100(this Bitmap bmp, string filename)
  {
      var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
      encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
       bmp.Save(filename, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
  }

public static void SaveJPG100(this Bitmap bmp, Stream stream)
{
    var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
    bmp.Save(stream, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
}

public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

    foreach (var codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }

    // Return 
    return null;
}
}
```

To implement:

```
   WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage( "http://www.cnn.com", @"C:\Some Folder\Test.jpg");
   websiteToImage.Generate();
```

Comment: thanks, where do i need to put this in ASPX file or? :  WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage( "http://www.cnn.com", @"C:\Some Folder\Test.jpg");
   websiteToImage.Generate();

Comment: it goes in your .cs file. Connect a button to a function or on the load you can put that in there. Or you can do a <script runat="server">
WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage( "http://www.cnn.com", @"C:\Some Folder\Test.jpg");
   websiteToImage.Generate();
 </script>

Comment: the second part can go in your aspx, but it's better to do it in your cs.