# Save current page to image

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, blob

I'm working on a project which requires to save the current page in an image. I found some examples in Javascript to create a blob of page, but what I would like to do is save the page in a file.

My question is, is it possible to save the content of a page in an image file?

Does a plugin exist to do it directly ?

If not, is it possible to save the blob and render the blob in C# to create an image?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window) could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save a page as an image, you can use http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```