# browser.Document.ScrollRectangle.Width is not returning the correct value

Tags: c#, image, webbrowser-control

I am trying to convert a webpage to an image using the following approach posted on stackoverflow: 
[Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)

however, i am running into issues with certain html where the following code:

```
var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
int width = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width; //width is returning 33017
int height = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height; //height is returning 8145
browser.ClientSize = new Size(width, height);
browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
browser.BringToFront();
browser.DrawToBitmap(m_Bitmap, browser.Bounds);

// Save as file? 
if (m_FileName.Length > 0)
    m_Bitmap.SaveImage(m_FileName, m_FileType, m_FileQuality);
m_Bitmap.Dispose();
```

The expected results ares 
width = 600
height = 8186

but I am getting some crazy results instead:
width = 33017
height = 8145

I can't figure out why the width is incorrect.

Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebsitetoImage is failing due to bad HTML in. Fixed the HTML the image is then saved correctly.